# Create another shortcut `~~` like `~` (home directory)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tilde

I want `~~` to point to a different directory so I can use it as a shortcut. I want it to have exactly same functionalities as `~`. How can I do this?

Comment: You might be better off with [zsh named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories)

Comment: Just found an interesting solution to the problem http://superuser.com/a/565825/398328

Comment: @VarunAgw haha, Funny find, right as I had thought of the same solution. Shame. I thought i was a unique butterfly for a minute :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, there is a way, it's not a great way, but it's a way, haha!

Add the following to your `/etc/passwd` file:

```
~:x:1111:99:special Character user:/test:/sbin/nologin
```

replace the `1111` as the UID with something that makes sense, replace `/test` with the directory you want `~~` to mimic.

`99` on my system is the `nobody` group. I recommend you to do this to make sure it's a group with **no** permissions on any file that will ever get used. Theoretically with `/sbin/nologin` as the shell, it should not be able to be used, it also will not have an `/etc/shadow` entry so it won't have a password. Theoretically should be fine, but make sure that it doesn't somehow let you log in as the account.

As a side note: I am not in any way saying this is a good idea, but it will accomplish the functionality that you want.

EDIT: For completeness’ sake this was suggested by @VarunAgw:

You could add the user as normal with `useradd -s /sbin/nologin -N tmp` and then modify `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` to change the user `tmp` to `~` and change the location of the home directory.

Comment: True. good suggestion. I'm unsure how i feel about legitimizing it with a `shadow` entry but i suppose as long as no password is set its not really an additional risk.

Comment: Old question/answer, I know, but it surfaced when someone asked it again yesterday (and we didn't realize it was a duplicate until the question's title was edited).  I came up with almost the [same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658158/432493).  Note that `useradd --badname --no-user-group --non-unique -u 1000 -g 1000 --shell /sbin/nologin -f0 -e0 --home-dir <desired_directory> "~"` pretty much gives you everything in one command line.  See my linked answer for more details on the results.

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of CDPATH and put a directory literally named `~~`  in one of your CDPATH components.

From `man bash` (but CDPATH is available even in `sh`)

> The search path for the cd command.  This is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for
>   destination directories specified by the cd command.  A sample value
>   is ".:~:/usr".

That will allow you to do `cd ~~`.

If you want to do things like `vi ~~/someFile` from anywhere in the directory tree, then you're out of luck if you insist on `~~` literally  unless you hack your shell, however, you can use variables or environment variable to store your magic directories so you can do, e.g, `$tilda/someFile`

I usually put often-accessed files inside shortly named directories in my home directory so I can access them with paths such as `~/b` or `~/l`.

Naturally, you can usually replace directories with symlinks to directories as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The shell's `~` tilde expansion is *mostly* programmable. It expands either to the user directory of the system username declared in its trailing context *(and an excellent solution along these lines has already been offered)*, the value of the `$HOME` shell variable, *or* not at all.

So:

```sh
(HOME=/tmp; cd ~)
pwd; echo "$HOME"
```

---

```sh
/tmp
/home/mikeserv
```

I change `$HOME` all of the time, and I keep a function in my shell's environment file for resetting it:

```sh
home(){
    HOME=~$USER
    cd ~; pwd
}
```

If you want to use the `~` tilde in some way that doesn't refer to your home directory, then *do so*. Just reassign `$HOME`. Don't be afraid of it. `$HOME` is just a shell variable like any other.

---

Another suggestion I have is only a slight expansion on @PSkocik's excellent advice about using `$CDPATH`. One thing he didn't mention, though, is that you can use and alter `$CDPATH` inline without changing the current shell value for `$CDPATH` at all. For example:

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/1/2
CDPATH=/tmp cd 1/2
```

---

```
/tmp/1/2
```

`cd` is necessarily a shell builtin, but it is not a POSIX *special* shell builtin, and so declaring the value for `$CDPATH` doesn't affect its current shell value. If you use it as I did above `$CDPATH`'s value is only altered for the environment of the one `cd` command, and is restored to its previous value afterward. I tend to find the above technique most useful when used in combination with history completion. I'll do the above thing, change to a directory, run a few commands, then press up until I come back to my `cd` command and backspace a path segment or two to move elsewhere.

---

Now if you combine these two concepts then you can make a previously used command mean something entirely different the next time you use it.

```sh
for HOME in /tmp ~
do  mkdir -p ~/1/2
    CDPATH=~ cd 1/2
done
```

---

```
/tmp/1/2
/home/mikeserv/1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly well as a bash function:

```
$ function ~~ { cd /tmp; }
$ pwd
/home/jackman
$ ~~
$ pwd
/tmp
$ cd -
$ pwd
/home/jackman
```

Here's another approach that comes a little closer (I know I'm not getting that close the to requirements)

```
function ~~ { echo /test; }
```

Then with a couple more characters:

```
cd `~~`/subdir
vi `~~`/file
```

Comment: Well, `cd ~~/foo/bar` isn't going to work so well, or `vim ~~/foo.txt`, etc...

Comment: The question is unclear. If that's the desired usage, I'd use the `CDPATH` variable to handle the `cd` case.

Comment: Agree it's not fully clear, but OP does ask for it to work like `~`. And `~` is not used like a command.

Comment: I found it fairly understandable myself, if not completely spelled out. The problem with `CDPATH` is it doesn't work for commands outside of....CD. IE you could `cd ~~` or `cd ~~/testdir1` but you could not `vim ~~testdir1`

Comment: you might do better with an alias that calls a function. like `alias cd~='HOME=$OTHER_HOME; home(){  cd -- "$1"; HOME=~$USER; unset -f home;}; home '`