# How do I make a shortcut to a path using two tilde characters '~~' (or similar) in WSL/Ubuntu/Bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu/Linux world, so don't be hard on me.

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows with WSL2 and the bash shell. Sometimes I want to copy files from Windows to Ubuntu or the other way around. I found some tutorials online on how to do this, and the simplest way is to navigate to `/mnt/c/Users/<your_user>`.

I want to create a variable like tilde `~` that would mean my Windows user's home directory. I thought about using double tilde `~~` since I saw that it isn't reserved or something.

I created an executable file in `/bin` named `~~` which would `echo` the necessary path. But that is cumbersome to use.

Is there a way to create a special character like `~`? If not is there a better way to do this?

The end result I'd like is to be able to do something like:

```
cp ~~/Desktop/somefile.txt ~/somefile.txt
```

Comment: For even more fun ... Now that muru edited the title to reference the `~~`, there's a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232838/create-another-shortcut-like-home-directory?rq=1) that shows up here with *even more* suggestions on how to do this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution under WSL is to create a symlink in my home directory to my Windows profile.  I personally use:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/<username> ~/winhome
```

But you could shorten it.  Under `bash`, at least `~~` *appears* to work as the symlink name as well, but I'm worried that in certain cases it could be misinterpreted.  If you want to try that route:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/<username> ~/~~
```

Then accessing it becomes something like:

```
cp ~/myfile ~/~~/Documents/
```

Answer (score 13):

In your case, you can likely use a shell variable instead. You can call it `$WH` e.g. which is still reasonably short:

```
~$ export WH=/mnt/c/Users/your_user
```

This will set the variable `WH` to your Windows home directory and export it as environment variable. You can then use this variable as in

```
~$ cp $WH/Desktop/somefile.txt ~/somefile.txt
```

To make this setting permanent, you can add this variable specification to your `.bashrc` file.

**Note** that if the path to your Windows home directory contains spaces, you have to quote the path in the variable definition and in any later use:

```
export WH="/mnt/c/Users/your user"
```

in your `.bashrc` and

```
~$ cp "$WH"/Desktop/somefile.txt ~/somefile.txt
```

when using on the console.

Answer (score 10):

I know the question is tagged `bash`, but if you use `zsh`, you can do this:

```
hash -d w='/mnt/c/Users/<your_user>'
```

With that, `~w` would expand to that path. This is a ["static named directory"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories). It's like AdminBee's suggestion using variable expansion, but one difference is that tab completion would work for expanding paths under `~w/`. Also, if you're under that directory and your prompt is set to display your current directory, it would show the short version with the named directory rather than the expanded full path.

`~` is an invalid character for this feature, so `~~` can't be used.

Answer (score 9):

Also, for a method of @JoL's answer that works on most shells (at least Bash, Fish, Zsh, and even Dash), you can simply create a new user named `w` with a home directory pointing to your Windows' user profile.  Then `~w/` becomes the shortcut.  It also appears to be possible to use `~` for the username, resulting in a `~~` shortcut.  See below for details.

There's really no downside to creating a user for this purpose on WSL, since there's no concept of user-level security (i.e. `wsl -u root` already gives you full access to everything in a WSL instance without a password).

A simple ...

```
sudo useradd --home-dir /mnt/c/Users/<username> w
```

... will work for WSL.  However, "best practice" would probably be something more like:

```
sudo useradd --no-user-group --non-unique -u 1000 -g 1000 --shell /sbin/nologin -f0 -e0 --home-dir /mnt/c/Users/<username> w
```

This would create a user `w` with the same user id and group id (1000:1000) as the primary WSL user (just a personal preference on my part to avoid polluting the system with unnecessary uids/gids).  That user would have the nologin shell, an expired password, and a locked account.  Again, not that this extra "security" is really needed on WSL anyway.

As with JoL's answer, this will allow:

```
cp ~/myfile ~w/Documents/
```

And with the caveat that this could cause problems in some corner cases, you can use `useradd`'s `--badname` option to force it to accept `~` as a username:

```
sudo useradd --badname --home-dir /mnt/c/Users/<username> "~" # or ...
sudo useradd --badname --no-user-group --non-unique -u 1000 -g 1000 --shell /sbin/nologin -f0 -e0 --home-dir /mnt/c/Users/<username> "~"
```

Resulting in your original request for:

```
cp ~/myfile ~~/Documents
```